# Receive an alert when the marker is outside the specified area (Google Maps API)

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

I am new to Google Maps and I need to receive an alert when the marker moves outside the circles, I have already created the map and added some circles to represent the areas in which the marker can stay, outside of them I need to show a alert announcing that this is not a coverage area.

My code is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    const citymap = {
           escalon: {
             center: { lat: 13.701984532461921, lng: -89.23395010808454 },
           },
         };
         const citymap1 = {
           matriz: {
             center: { lat: 13.699526, lng: -89.196691 },
           },
         };
         const citymap2 = {
           plaza: {
             center: { lat: 13.699581, lng: -89.189770 },
           },
         };
         const citymap3 = {
           ahuachapan: {
             center: { lat: 13.920266, lng: -89.847658 },
           },
         };
         const citymap4 = {
           sanMiguel: {
             center: { lat: 13.484937, lng: -88.177339 },
           },
         };
         const citymap5 = {
           santaAna: {
             center: { lat: 13.993704, lng: -89.556913 },
           },
         };
         const citymap6 = {
           sonsonate: {
             center: { lat: 13.720177, lng: -89.727801 },
           },
         };
        function initialize() {
            // Creating map object
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.701277, -89.224468),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var vMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.701277, -89.224468),
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(vMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
                $("#txtLat").val("https://www.google.es/maps/dir/" + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " +  evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));

                map.panTo(evt.latLng);
            });
            
            for (const city in citymap) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const vMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.701277, -89.224468),
                draggable: true
            });
           }
           for (const city in citymap) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
               strokeColor: "#0066cc",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: "#0066cc",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map,
               center: citymap[city].center,
               radius: 8000,
             });
           }
            for (const city in citymap1) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
               strokeColor: "#0066cc",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: "#0066cc",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map,
               center: citymap1[city].center,
               radius: 5000,
             });
           }
            for (const city in citymap2) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
               strokeColor: "#0066cc",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: "#0066cc",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map,
               center: citymap2[city].center,
               radius: 5000,
             });
           }
           for (const city in citymap3) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
               strokeColor: "#0066cc",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: "#0066cc",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map,
               center: citymap3[city].center,
               radius: 7000,
             });
           }
           for (const city in citymap4) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
               strokeColor: "#0066cc",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: "#0066cc",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map,
               center: citymap4[city].center,
               radius: 7000,
             });
           }
           for (const city in citymap5) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
               strokeColor: "#0066cc",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: "#0066cc",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map,
               center: citymap5[city].center,
               radius: 7000,
             });
           }
           for (const city in citymap6) {
             // Add the circle for this city to the map.
             const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
               strokeColor: "#0066cc",
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: "#0066cc",
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map,
               center: citymap6[city].center,
               radius: 7000,
             });
           }
            
            

            // centers the map on markers coords
            map.setCenter(vMarker.position);

            // adds the marker on the map
            vMarker.setMap(map);
        }
        
    </script>
</head>

<body  onload="initialize();">
<div id='map_canvas' style='width: auto; height: 500px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have left you this example code in order to have a broader panorama of my problem, because precisely what I am trying to do is a type of home delivery and the areas in blue marked on the map are the areas in which If there is coverage of my home delivery, but if the marker is located outside of them, or if the client moves them outside of them, I need the alert to be displayed to warn that it cannot be, I appreciate all the support, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the bounds `getBounds()` of the circle and check if the location of the marker is within those bounds like so:

```js
function init() {
    var
        contentCenter = '<span class="infowin">Center Marker (draggable)</span>',
        contentA = '<span class="infowin">Marker A (draggable)</span>',
        contentB = '<span class="infowin">Marker B (draggable)</span>';
    var
        latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.081476, -94.510574),
        latLngCMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0814, -94.5105),
        latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(37.2, -94.1),
        latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -93),
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: latLngCenter,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        }),
        markerCenter = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLngCMarker,
            title: 'Location',
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        }),
        infoCenter = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentCenter
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLngA,
            title: 'Location',
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        }),
        infoA = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentA
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLngB,
            title: 'Location',
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        }),
        infoB = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentB
        })
        // exemplary setup: 
        // Assumes that your map is signed to the var "map"
        // Also assumes that your marker is named "marker"
        ,
        circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            clickable: false,
            // metres
            radius: 100000,
            fillColor: '#fff',
            fillOpacity: .6,
            strokeColor: '#313131',
            strokeOpacity: .4,
            strokeWeight: .8
        });
    // attach circle to marker
    circle.bindTo('center', markerCenter, 'position');

    var
    // get the Bounds of the circle
    bounds = circle.getBounds()
    // Note spans
    ,
        noteA = jQuery('.bool#a'),
        noteB = jQuery('.bool#b');

    noteA.text(bounds.contains(latLngA));
    noteB.text(bounds.contains(latLngB));

    // get some latLng object and Question if it's contained in the circle:
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'dragend', function() {
        latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(markerCenter.position.lat(), markerCenter.position.lng());
        bounds = circle.getBounds();
        noteA.text(bounds.contains(latLngA));
        noteB.text(bounds.contains(latLngB));
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'dragend', function() {
        latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(markerA.position.lat(), markerA.position.lng());
        noteA.text(bounds.contains(latLngA));
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'dragend', function() {
        latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(markerB.position.lat(), markerB.position.lng());
        noteB.text(bounds.contains(latLngB));
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'click', function() {
        infoCenter.open(map, markerCenter);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'click', function() {
        infoA.open(map, markerA);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'click', function() {
        infoB.open(map, markerB);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'drag', function() {
        infoCenter.close();
        noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
        noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'drag', function() {
        infoA.close();
        noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'drag', function() {
        infoB.close();
        noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
    });
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0
}
html, 
body, 
#map {
    height: 100%; 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: .9em; 
    color: #fff;
}
#note { 
    text-align: center;
    padding: .3em; 10px; 
    background: #009ee0; 
}
.bool {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #313131;
}
.info {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}
.infowin {
    color: #313131;
}
#title,
.bool{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="note">
  <span id="title">&raquo;Inside the circle?&laquo;</span>
  <hr />
  <span class="info">Marker <strong>A</strong>:
    <span id="a" class="bool"></span>
  </span> &larr;&diams;&rarr;
  <span class="info">Marker <strong>B</strong>:
    <span id="b" class="bool"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="map">test</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=init&libraries=&v=weekly&key=YOUR_API_KEY" async></script>
```